# How to do a grid search programmatically for SVM in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm, libsvm

What is the piece of code in Java that I can use to do a grid search for SVM parameters using LibSVM in Weka?

Currently, I am able to search for a good value for only 1 parameter using the following piece of code:

```
LibSVM svm = new LibSVM();
    svm.setKernelType(new SelectedTag(2, LibSVM.TAGS_KERNELTYPE));
    svm.setDegree(2);
    //Run a cross validation to select the right parameters
    CVParameterSelection ps = new CVParameterSelection();
    ps.setClassifier(svm);
    ps.setNumFolds(5);  // using 5-fold CV
    ps.addCVParameter("G 0.1 10 100");
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a reliable API:
http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/api/0.1.6/libsvm/GridSearch.html

The GridSearch constructor accepts a LibSVM object, Dataset object and an integer representing the number of folds to use for the grid search. The search method can then be called on the GridSearch object. The inputs for this method are the initial SVM parameters (including C and Gamma) and the outputs are the optimal C and Gamma values.

Comment: This links fails to open :(